# Can't repeat js function in same page

Tags: javascript, html

Please be kind I'm a real beginner.

I'm trying to use this function twice on the same page (in different sections) but am unable to do this. I assume I somehow need to label it differently each time I use it, but can't figure out where.

Maybe the functions are not labeled correctly but I have tried trying this.

Here is the JS

```js
(function () {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ["ms", "moz", "webkit", "o"];
  for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + "RequestAnimationFrame"];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame =
      window[vendors[x] + "CancelAnimationFrame"] ||
      window[vendors[x] + "CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];
  }

  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function () {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      }, timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };

  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
})();

var Nodes = {
  // Settings
  density: 20,
  reactionSensitivity: 10,

  points: [],
  lines: [[], [], [], []],
  mouse: { x: 10, y: 10, down: false },

  animation: null,

  canvas: null,
  context: null,

  init: function () {
    // Set up the visual canvas
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("stripes2");
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.context.lineJoin = "bevel";
    this.canvas.width = window.innerHeight*2;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.style.display = "block";

    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMove, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUp, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", this.mouseOut, false);

    window.onresize = function (event) {
      Nodes.canvas.width = (window.innerHeight*2);
      Nodes.canvas.height = Math.max(window.innerHeight, 1000);
      Nodes.onWindowResize();
    };

    this.preparePoints();
    this.draw();
  },

  preparePoints: function () {
    // Clear the current points
    this.points = [];
    this.lines = [[], [], [], [], []];

    var width, height, i;
    var center = window.innerHeight / 2;

    for (i = -1000; i < this.canvas.width + 1000; i += this.density) {
      var line1 = { y: center - 17, originalY: center - -100, color: "#249FA4" };
      var line2 = { y: center - 17, originalY: center - -50, color: "#3DB8B5" };
      var line3 = { y: center - 17, originalY: center - 0, color: "#F8DCAA" };
      var line4 = { y: center - 17, originalY: center - 50, color: "#F1B30A" };
      var line5 = { y: center - 17, originalY: center - 100, color: "#E77419" };

      line1["x"] = i;
      line1["originalX"] = i;

      line2["x"] = i;
      line2["originalX"] = i;
      
       line3["x"] = i;
      line3["originalX"] = i;
      
       line4["x"] = i;
      line4["originalX"] = i;
      
       line5["x"] = i;
      line5["originalX"] = i;

      this.points.push(line1);
      this.points.push(line2);
       this.points.push(line3);
      this.points.push(line4);
       this.points.push(line5);
    

      this.lines[0].push(line1);
      this.lines[1].push(line2);
      this.lines[2].push(line3);
      this.lines[3].push(line4);
      this.lines[4].push(line5);
    }
  },

  updatePoints: function () {
    var i, currentPoint, theta, distance;

    for (i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
      currentPoint = this.points[i];

      theta = Math.atan2(
        currentPoint.y - this.mouse.y,
        currentPoint.x - this.mouse.x
      );

      if (this.mouse.down) {
        distance =
          (this.reactionSensitivity * 300) /
          Math.sqrt(
            (this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) * (this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) +
              (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y) * (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y)
          );
      } else {
        distance =
          (this.reactionSensitivity * 150) /
          Math.sqrt(
            (this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) * (this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) +
              (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y) * (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y)
          );
      }

      currentPoint.x +=
        Math.cos(theta) * distance +
        (currentPoint.originalX - currentPoint.x) * 0.07;
      currentPoint.y +=
        Math.sin(theta) * distance +
        (currentPoint.originalY - currentPoint.y) * 0.07;
    }
  },

  drawPoints: function () {
    var i, currentPoint;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var line = this.lines[i];
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.lineJoin = "round";
      this.context.moveTo(line[0].x, line[0].y);
      this.context.strokeStyle = line[0].color;
      this.context.lineWidth = 50;
      for (var j = 1; j < line.length - 2; j++) {
        var point = line[j];

        var xc = (point.x + line[j + 1].x) / 2;
        var yc = (point.y + line[j + 1].y) / 2;

        this.context.quadraticCurveTo(point.x, point.y, xc, yc);
      }
      this.context.stroke();
      this.context.closePath();
    }
  },

  draw: function () {
    this.animation = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      Nodes.draw();
    });

    this.clear();
    this.updatePoints();
    this.drawPoints();
  },

  clear: function () {
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;
  },

  mouseDown: function (event) {
    Nodes.mouse.down = true;
  },

  mouseUp: function (event) {
    Nodes.mouse.down = false;
  },

  mouseMove: function (event) {
    Nodes.mouse.x = event.pageY;
    Nodes.mouse.y = event.pageY;
  },

  mouseOut: function (event) {
    Nodes.mouse.x = -1000;
    Nodes.mouse.y = -1000;
    Nodes.mouse.down = false;
  },

  // Resize and redraw the canvas.
  onWindowResize: function () {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.animation);
    this.preparePoints();
    this.draw();
  }
};

// Start the app.
setTimeout(function () {
  Nodes.init();
}, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="stripes2" class="container">
```

Many thanks

Comment: you use var for the Nodes variable so if you use it twice it will be overriden

Comment: I suppose you meant to use that code on multiple canvas elements. The canvas gets initialized with `Nodes.init();` that has the canvas id hardcoded inside as: `document.getElementById("stripes2");` ... you should try passing that id as a parameter and see if it will work on multiple canvas

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I'm very new to the terminology. How do I do that?

Comment: LK77, so I just need to change to add another variable - say nodes2?